# Capture Tags with preg_match

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, matching

I use this function for reading and show information I want from RSS vimeo:

```
$url=array('http://vimeo.com/channels/hdnature/videos/rss'); 



foreach($url as $value){
$homepage = file_get_contents($value);
$movies = new SimpleXMLElement($homepage);
      foreach($movies->channel->item as $opt){


    $title= $opt->title;
    $tittle=mysql_real_escape_string($title);

    $link=$opt->link;
    $links=mysql_real_escape_string($link); 


    $des=$opt->description;
    $dess=mysql_real_escape_string($des);
    //Use that namespace
     $namespaces = $opt->getNameSpaces(true);
    //Now we don't have the URL hard-coded
     $dc = $opt->children($namespaces['dc']); 
    //echo $dc->publisher;
    //echo $dc->creator;
   //echo $link;


    $imgpattern = '/href="(.*?)"/i';
    preg_match($imgpattern, $des, $matches);
    $imageurl['image'] = $matches[1];
    echo $imageurl['image'];

    $tag = '/">(.*?)<\/a>/';
    preg_match($tag, $des, $matches);
    $tagurl['name'] = $matches[1];
    echo $tagurl['name'];
```

I have this list of tags inside the `<description></description>` field:

```
<p><strong>Tags:</strong> 
<a href="http://vimeo.com/tag:art">Art</a>, 
<a href="http://vimeo.com/tag:film">Film</a>,
<a href="http://vimeo.com/tag:movie">Movie</a>,
<a href="http://vimeo.com/tag:cinema">Cinema</a>,
<a href="http://vimeo.com/tag:creation">Creation</a>,
<a href="http://vimeo.com/tag:concept">Concept</a>,
<a href="http://vimeo.com/tag:experimental">Experimental</a>,
<a href="http://vimeo.com/tag:sound">Sound</a>,
<a href="http://vimeo.com/tag:music">Music</a>,
<a href="http://vimeo.com/tag:motion">Motion</a>,
<a href="http://vimeo.com/tag:copyleft">Copyleft</a>
and 
<a href="http://vimeo.com/tag:videoart">Videoart</a>
</p>
```

I search to save in my database only word like Art, Movie, Cinema, etc.

I need to save a list with brackets and I try to use preg_match.

I have this function:

```
$tag = '/</strong>(.*?)</a></p>/';
preg_match($tag, $des, $matches);
$taglist['name'] = $matches[1];
echo $taglist['name'];
```

but I receive only a error and not the result I'm hoping for.

Comment: i want store in my database all word i find before TAGS: whitout link and separate whit brackets like this : cineme,arte,movie,sport,etc..

Comment: Yes i want store all words after "Tags:" you can explane me how i can do this ?

Comment: **Don't use regular expressions to parse HTML**. You cannot reliably parse HTML with regular expressions. As soon as the HTML changes from your expectations, your code will be broken. See http://htmlparsing.com/php.html for examples of how to properly parse HTML with PHP modules.

Comment: @AndyLester you can explane me whit some code example how i can retrieve the word after the Tags and store in database ? I'm not a coder and i don't know how is the right way for use the Dom module. Thanks

Comment: See htmlparsing.com/php.html for examples of how to properly parse HTML with PHP modules.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$des = '<p><strong>Tags:</strong> 
<a href="http://vimeo.com/tag:art">Art</a>, 
<a href="http://vimeo.com/tag:film">Film</a>,
<a href="http://vimeo.com/tag:movie">Movie</a>,
<a href="http://vimeo.com/tag:cinema">Cinema</a>,
<a href="http://vimeo.com/tag:creation">Creation</a>,
<a href="http://vimeo.com/tag:concept">Concept</a>,
<a href="http://vimeo.com/tag:experimental">Experimental</a>,
<a href="http://vimeo.com/tag:sound">Sound</a>,
<a href="http://vimeo.com/tag:music">Music</a>,
<a href="http://vimeo.com/tag:motion">Motion</a>,
<a href="http://vimeo.com/tag:copyleft">Copyleft</a>
and 
<a href="http://vimeo.com/tag:videoart">Videoart</a>
</p>';
$tag = '/">(.*?)<\/a>/';
preg_match_all($tag, $des, $matches);
print_r($matches[1]);
```

Comment: Sorry but is my faul , the code below are the result from reading rss feed from vimeo whit the code i have add . So is not possible using your solution but maybe you can help me one more time .

Comment: @junkfood i answered to the current question, you may edit the question ?

Comment: i add more explanation and more code for explane my dubt, the code you are kindly send me don't work because i can retrieve the list of tags inside the field description on feed

Comment: you can help me one more time ?